# How to do event handling for dynamically introduced elements in page in yui3

Tags: yui, yui3

I am having trouble to do event handling for elements which are dynamically introduced in the page.I currently use:

Y.on("click",function,'.dynamicObj');
Here suppose 'dynamicObj' is the class which I add when I make these element.But Y.on has the polling issue so sometimes my code worked properly sometime it didn't.

So can somebody please guide on how to eventhandling for dynamically add elements of the page at the same time no polling issue is faced.

Answer (score 0):

You usually listen to the event on an element that contains the dynamic element and let the event bubble up to reach it.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using 'on' use 'delegate' to bind event.
ex `Y.one('<already present element selector>').delegate('<event>', <binder function name>, '<element on which event is to be binded>')`